# How to plot a piecewise linear function?

Tags: matlab

I need matlab code of this graph according to these conditions which is dependent on the r value.
There three different case in the graph. First case; if the r value is lower than r1 and above than 0 use the formula L1.
Second case; if the r value between r1 and r2 use the formula L2. Last case; if the r value greater than r2 use the formula L3.
Could you help me ?

```
    if r < r1
    s=r*(r1/s1);
elseif r1<r & r<r2
    x=tan((r2-r1)/(s2-s1))
    s(r-r1)*x
else
    s=r*(r2/s2)
end
```

My graph:

[image: my graph]

Formulas:

[image: formulas]

Comment: Weird that we're seeing the [same question from multiple users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64544270/843953). Is someone's professor asking them to get help from Stack Overflow? [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/843953) 
[Asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: Maybe, If you will help me, i will be very happy.

Comment: Assuming this is going to be used to transform an array/image. Find the slopes of each line. Find the `runs` for the given input by subtracting the lower bound of each range by the input. Then multiply the `slope × run + offset`. The offset will be the starting point of each piecewise portion.

Comment: _"How to plot a piecewise linear function?"_ `plot([0 r1 r2], [0 s1 s2]);`. You don't need the slope or offset to plot the graph

Comment: Showing a code attempt is always appreciated and will yield the most responses to your question. Typically effort received ∝ effort given.

Comment: I couldn't do it.Can you give me matlab codes? please

Comment: if r < r1
    s=r*(r1/s1);
elseif r1<r & r<r2
    x=tan((r2-r1)/(s2-s1))
    s(r-r1)*x
else
    s=r*(r2/s2)
end

Comment: What's wrong with `plot([0 r1 r2 255], [0 s1 s2 255]);`?

Comment: @İbrahimMeteÇiçek Is this for contrast stretching?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I think they're coming from a point of contrast stretching since a similar question recently deleted indicated that premise.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 I don't interpret questions. OP asked how to plot it and this line plots it.

Comment: yes, it is.....

Answer (score 2):

You can plot the given graph with ([plot](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html))

```
plot([0 r1 r2 255], [0 s1 s2 255]);
```

You don't need the slope or the offset. All plots are piecewise linear functions. Matlab draws straight lines from one coordinate to the next coordinate. You don't need the whole function.

Matlab is a mathematical programming language. You don't have to create piecewise linear functions by yourself. Usually you should avoid loops and if-conditions to make your code more readable and more performant. You can use ([interp1](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html))

```
s = interp1([0 r1 r2 255], [0 s1 s2 255], r);
```

to calculate the values between two coordinates.

Comment: Sir, i need seperate  mathematical functions of these 3  cases on the line.

Comment: But you are using `s1` and `s2` in your provided code? How can you use these variables if you don't know how to find them?

Comment: @İbrahimMeteÇiçek I added a Matlab function to create a piecewise linear function.